# Texstudio 4.2.3 win qt6 What date version of vcruntime140.dll should I be using and what location does texstudio point to please?

Tags: texstudio

The question is the title of the post as I have a system error, in both portable or installed texstudio, error details below;

Error is vcruntime140.dll not found, specifically, "The code execution cannot proceed because VCRUNTIME140.dll was not found.  Reinstalling the program may fix this problem." Texstudio fails to launch from a fresh install.

I'm running on (not virtual nor sandboxed)
Windows10 v21H2(19044.1645)
Miktex basic-miktex-22.3-x64.exe (3/18/2022)
texstudio-4.2.3-win-portable-qt6.zip
texstudio-4.2.3-win-qt6.exe

The vcruntime140.dll is on my system.  I was already running texstudio 4.2.3 qt6 very successfully.
Last week there became an issue compiling a file with pdflatex, and the Miktex log showed an installation error.  I fully uninstalled both Miktex and texstudio and then reinstalled both.
Using the Miktex console I can launch Texworks and compile and create pdfs fine.  I can do this running either an installed or portable MikTex version.
An installed or portable texstudio produce the missing dll error described above.

The root of my texstudio is F:
vcruntime140.dll is in F:\miktex-portable\texmfs\install\miktex\bin\x64
The file details from the MVS C Runtime Library are;
name    vcruntime140.dll
version 14.30.30704.0
date    02/12/2021 11:32
size    94.8kb

This must be a unique problem so temporarily I am using TeXMaker to compile and create pdfs.
The root of my TeXMaker is F:
vcruntime140.dll is in F:\TeXMaker\texmakerwin64usb
The file details from the MVS C Runtime Library are;
name    vcruntime140.dll
version 14.29.30040.0
date    12/10/2021 10:13
size    94.8kb

What date version of vcruntime140.dll should I be using and what location does texstudio point to.
Any suggestions please or other information would you need to get my installation running ?
Many thanks
CPF

Answer (score 0):

Copied vcruntime140.dll from MikTek installation into Texstudio installation root folder (same location as texstudio.exe).  This allowed texstudio to launch without errors.
Issue is solved for me.

Comment: It would be better to edit this information into your question.  It's always permitted for someone posting a question to edit it.